# Evaluating position vector between 2 hydrogen states

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises

I am trying to find the quantity:
$$\langle1,0,0|\vec r|2,0,0\rangle$$
Where $|n,l,m\rangle$ are the hydrogen states.  For this, can I just integrate r from? 0 to infinity?  Or do I have to break it into the x, y, z components and go over all space?

Comment: Is your integral the scalar quantity 
$$
\left<1,0,0
\middle|r
\middle|2,0,0
\right>,
$$
or the vector quantity
$$
\left<1,0,0
\middle|\vec r
\middle|2,0,0
\right>
=
\left<1,0,0
\middle|x\hat x
\middle|2,0,0
\right>
+
\left<1,0,0
\middle|y\hat y
\middle|2,0,0
\right>
+
\left<1,0,0
\middle|z\hat z
\middle|2,0,0
\right>
\quad\quad?
$$
The first you have in an answer; the second is zero since the states with $\ell,m=0,0$ are spherically symmetric.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you must integrate over all space. When you work with spherically symmetric systems like the hydrogen atom, the eigenstates $|n,l,m\rangle$ separate into functions of $(r, \theta, \phi)$: $\psi(\vec{r}) = R(r)\Theta(\theta)\Phi(\phi)$. Because of this, it is vastly easier to do the integrals in the $(r,\theta,\phi)$ space: you can carry out the integral over each coordinate independently of the other coordinates.

In this particular case, because $l = m = 0$, you should find that the $\theta$ and $\phi$ integrations are particularly easy, leaving you just $r$. You should find that this particular case will allow you to derive some [selection rules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_rule).

Answer (score 0):

ITHER :

You write $\textbf{r} = x\textbf{i} + y\textbf{j} + z\textbf{k} = r\sin{\theta}\cos{\phi}\textbf{i} + r\sin{\theta} \sin{\phi}\textbf{j} + r\cos{\theta}\textbf{k} $,

work out the values of $x$, $y$ and $z$ separately and from them work out the values of $\phi$ and $\theta$

using $ \theta = \arctan(\frac{z}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2} })$ and $ \phi = \arctan(\frac{y}{x }$)

OR:

find the values of $r$, $\phi$ and $\theta$ using:

$ \langle r\rangle = \langle1,0,0|r|2,0,0\rangle $,

$ \langle \phi\rangle = \langle1,0,0|\phi|2,0,0\rangle $,

$ \langle \theta \rangle = \langle1,0,0|\theta|2,0,0\rangle $

which I think will be harder to compute algebraically because $\theta$ and $\phi$ appear both in linear terms and in trigonometric formulae.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this problem is as hard as it looks.  As others have pointed you will have an integral for each of the three cartesian directions: $r_x$, $r_y$, and $r_z$.  Each integral is a triple integral, best done in spherical coordinates.  First do the $\phi$ integral, then $\theta$, leaving $r$ for last.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the result can be given with zero calculation, by just noting that the wave functions $\left|n,0,0\right\rangle$ are radially symmetric, that is, invariant under arbitrary rotations around the origin, and the integration range is the whole space, and therefore also invariant under rotations, and therefore the result also has to be invariant under arbitrary rotations around the origin. On the other hand, the result is a vector. But there exists only one rotationally invariant vector: The zero vector.

Answer (score -1):

That depends on what basis do you use. Since $|l,m,n⟩$ means the Schrödinger-eq. was solved in spherical coordinates, than you get the following:
$$
⟨1,0,0|r⃗ |2,0,0⟩=\int_VdV \Psi_{100}^*(\vec r)\vec r \Psi_{200}(\vec r)=$$$$=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\pi}\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}a_0^{3/2}}e^{-r/a_0}r \frac{1}{4\sqrt{2\pi}a_0^{3/2}}(2-\frac{r}{a_0})e^{-r/2a_0} r^2sin\theta \,dr\,d\theta \,d\phi
$$

Since in spherical coordinates, after integrating as per solid angle, $r⃗ \rightarrow r$, nothing depends on $\theta$ or $\phi$, so you need to integrate from 0 to $\infty$ as per $r$.

Source of wave functions: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/hydwf.html#c3

Comment: Something is wrong with this approach.  $\vec{r} = (r,0,0)$ does not uniquely identify a point in space the way $(x,y,z)$ does.

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to mention the problem is rotational symmetric, so one can integrate as per solid angle resulting in $4\pi$ and leaving an integral where one only need to integrate as per radius.

Comment: The matrix element is a vector, isn't it?  When you are finished, in what direction does that vector point?

Comment: Radial of course, in spherical coordinates, which in fact contains all three Descartes coordinate vectors. I think we are talking about the same based on your answer, I just tried to explain a little more detailed.

Comment: @HodossySzbolcs I'm afraid your approach is not correct.  Your calculation yields the matrix element for the *magnitude* of the position vector $\vec{r}$, not the vector itself.  Consider $<1S|\vec{r}|1S>$.  This matrix element gives the expectation value for the position of the electron in $|1S>$: zero.  Your method does not yield zero.  Contributions from diametrically opposite points should cancel, as $\vec{r}$ points in opposite directions at those two points.  In your scheme they do not cancel. The correct calculation is not hard, see my answer. With thought, no calculation is needed.

Comment: I never said it is a scalar, it point in the direction of radial unity vector, since it is in spherical coordinates. I think if you go in details a little bit more, you will see our answers are the same.

Comment: Maybe the vector notation in the integral is misleading, since I used sperical coordinates. I am removing them.

Comment: Can you verify that $<1,0,0|\vec{r}|1,0,0>=0$?

Comment: Of course not, but it should not be the case, since that expression gives you the expected value of whereabout of an electron in ground state, which in fact is not in the core of the atom, but around it. Check out this: http://www.quantumsciencephilippines.com/1379/finding-the-expectation-value-for-the-ground-state-of-a-hydrogen-atom/

Comment: Ok.  But I think the matrix element of $r$ is not the same as the matrix element of $\vec{r}$.  $<1S|\,r\,|1S>$ gives the most likely radius of the electron, $<1S|\,\vec{r}\,|1S>$ the most likely position.  So what is the OP's intent?  I interpreted it to be the matrix element of $\vec{r}$, as if he were trying to calculate the transition dipole matrix element.  This is homework so I won't write it, but I think you know what that value is.  Bottom line: you and I interpreted the question differently. (We should take the discussion offline at some point.)